# How to get connection with Human interface device (HID) using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, hid

I'm trying to integration Human interface device with my angular web app. I'm trying to find any library or example to connect and get the device detail of HID.

Please suggest any help here.

Thanks.

I have tried to library in NPM but not found and I was trying to with WebHID API.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a about the Angular, that is just a framework to build your website. In the end, it'd be transpiled to Javascript.

Assuming I don't understand which HID you're intending to show on your webpage;

- If it's server's HIDs, you can try to use [node-hid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-hid), and send the information you need or an interface to interact with it to the client.
- If it's client's HIDs, you're on the right track. You can use [WebHID](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/hid/)

  ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     device: HIDDevice | undefined;

     async connectHID() {
         if (!('hid' in navigator)) {
           console.error('WebHID is not supported in this browser.');
           return;
         }

         try {
           this.device = await (navigator as any).hid.requestDevice({ filters: [{ usagePage: 0x01, usage: 0x06 }] });
           await this.device.open();
           console.log('Device connected:', this.device);
         } catch (error) {
           console.error('Failed to connect to the HID device:', error);
         }
     }
   }
  ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But could you please let me know what is this `HIDDevice ` and from where I have to import.

Comment: Hi @SuryaSingh - I am not sure if there's a type for it yet. Otherwise you can create the interface from here https://wicg.github.io/webhid/#dom-hiddevice